# Multiple websites in one VPS instance with NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I still struggling with configuration of nginx for multiple websites in one virtual machine.
So If I do:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

after hit example1.com my nodejs page is loaded properly. But If I try to add second server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Nothing is working, also example1. So I wanna to load through example2.com default nginx location... Something like that:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example1.com;

    location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html index.htm;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

But it is always redirected to nginx root location.

How can I do that? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.JS?

You can refer my configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
}
```

or another one

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2387;
}
```

The first configuration direct to https redirect cycle.

And you said the default site, you can config something like that:

```
listen 80 default;
server_name xxxxx.com;
```